# Should I change the format of preprint before publishing it as a working paper?

Tags: publishers, preprint

I submit a paper to a journal which allows to publish the preprint as a working paper. After submission, I thought I can just take the version I just submitted and publish it on ResearchGate. But then I thought that it might be problematic to use the same format I used for submission, since then everyone knows to what journal I submitted (or at least, to what publisher). Then, if my paper gets rejected, everyone knows that.

Is this an important consideration? Is it important to change the format of the paper before putting it in a preprint archive?

Comment: I know how you feel on this, having been through a similar experience. but I think the answer may be opinionated or based on personal preference. I would say it is not that important, but others may differ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally, I wouldn't bother changing the format.  As a wise colleague once told me, if you aren't getting some papers rejected, you aren't submitting to good enough venues.  If you're proud of the work, there's no need to try to obfuscate where it's been submitted.

Answer (score 1):

You have no need to change the format of the preprint. Although you may not upload it in the publications section in RG, you may as well do so in the unpublished work section.